# Starting a new ViewController from a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, segue

I was wondering how I would start a new ViewController from a UIAlertView.To me it seems like you can't connect the viewControllers graphically the way you can with a button.

I have the UIAlertView set up in my first viewController like so:

```
UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Start New View Controller?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
```

Then I handle the different button clicks like so:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:    (NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex == 0){
    NSLog(@"Cancel");
}
if (buttonIndex == 1){
    NSLog(@"Yes");
    }
}
```

How would I start a second viewController (say viewContoller2) with this alertbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either start a view controller the regular way, or use a segue. For the segue, you'd do something like:

```
if (buttonIndex == 1){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGUE_IDENTIFIER" sender:self];
}
```

and later in the code, you set up the controller this way:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SEGUE_IDENTIFIER"]) {
        MyViewController *viewContoller2 = (MyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog("viewContoller2 is ready for use");
    }
}
```

or without segues, do:

```
if (buttonIndex == 1){
  MyViewController *viewContoller2 = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
  [self presentViewController:viewContoller2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Note that since it's April 1, I kept "viewContoller2" and its obvious typo. :)

Comment: More like first world anarchy!